# Who said something along the lines of us never knowing more than 1% of our sin?

Tags: sin, reference-request

I have pretty clear memories of John Piper quoting someone else saying that in this life we are never aware of more than 1% of our sin, with the implication being that as we grow in godliness we do see more and more of our sin, but that sin is so deep within us that we never understand the full scope of it.

But despite how clear my memories are, I haven't been able to find any trace of any kind of statement like this, whether by John Piper or anyone else. But I'm sure I didn't make it up myself! Has anyone heard anything like this, specifically with the idea of knowing X% of our sin?

Comment: I apologize for this comment not contributing to the answer, but there are a lot of percentages of what Americans think of sin in this [2018 Lenten research](https://www.christianitytoday.com/news/2018/march/lord-have-mercy-on-us-sinners-kyrie-lent-sin-surveys.html)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yeah, not really related to the quote I half remember. It was more that as our faith grows we become more aware of sin in our lives.